# How to convert dd-mmm-yyyy to date9 in sas

Tags: sas

Want to convert date = 01-SEP-2021 to date = 01SEP2021. I used this code to convert:

New date = input(compress(date,'-'),date9.);

But that didn't work. I also used substring to remove the parts of day month and year but seems this method is a bit lengthy.

Comment: Just to be clear, date is a character value, correct?

Comment: Seems type is numeric

Comment: If the type is numeric and it is displayed as `01-SEP-2021` then there is no conversion needed. You already have a date value.  If you really want it to display without the hyphens then just display it with the DATE9. format instead of the DATE11. format it is currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type is numeric and SAS already displays it as a date then it's a formatting issue.

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    modify have;
        format date date9.;
quit;
```

Otherwise, it must be a character and you have to convert it to a date and display it in `date9.` format.

```
data want;
    date     = '01-SEP-2021';
    new_date = input(date, anydtdte.); *anydtdte. automatically reads a variety of date formats;
    
    format new_date date9.;
run;
```